# Medium-strong (graph) homomorphisms

Tags: graph-theory, model-theory, universal-algebra

**Weak** (graph) homomorphisms are mappings $f: V(G) \rightarrow V(G')$ such that the images of connected nodes $x,y$ (in the source graph) are connected:

$$R(x,y) \rightarrow R(f(x),f(y)) = R(x',y')$$

[**Strong**](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Homomorphism) [(graph) homomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_%28mathematical_logic%29#Homomorphisms) are mappings $f: V(G) \rightarrow V(G')$ such that the *pre*-images of connected nodes $x',y'$ (in the target graph) **do exist** and are connected:

$$R(x',y') \rightarrow R(f^{-1}(x'),f^{-1}(y')) = R(x,y)$$

I wonder why "**medium-strong**" (graph) homomorphisms don't play a more prominent role, which one can rather simply define as mappings $f: V(G) \rightarrow V(G')$ such that the *pre*-images of connected nodes $x',y'$ are connected **if they exist**, which is (I hope) equivalent with:

$$\neg R(x,y) \rightarrow \neg R(f(x),f(y)) = \neg R(x',y')$$

Comment: I think the first two definitions are useful in the theory of embeddings and immersions; where would your definition be useful (or where did you encounter it)? I usually see those constructions posed as a sequence of evolving graphs indexed by time, in which edges are added as time passes.

Comment: @Eric: My question is for formal reasons (no real-world problem associated with it): There is a formally similar definition of homomorphism, why isn't it used? My guess of an answer: a medium-strong (graph) homomorphism is just a weak homomorphism in connection with the (trivial) graph complement operator. So it doesn't contribute something essentially new. Strong homomorphisms do, by requiring $f$ to be surjective (but only on connected nodes).